# Draw bounding box around nodes in graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I am trying to but a cloud around two nodes in a graph like this:

[image: graph with a cloud shape around two node]

However the cloud never ends up around the nodes but just to the right of the graph. Is there maybe a different syntax to style a group of nodes or to name them inside a graph. I used the `name=` option though previously I could always use a name in parenthesis.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs, graphdrawing, fit, shapes.callouts}
\usegdlibrary{layered}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
layered layout,
grow'=right,
level sep=.5cm,
sibling sep=.75cm,
nodes={draw, circle},
]
\graph {
  S[rectangle, inner sep=3mm]
  -- A
  -- { B[name=B, nudge down=4mm] -- C[name=C, nudge up=4mm] }
  -- D
  -- { E -- F, G -- H }
  -- I
  -- J
  -- K
  -- Z[rectangle, inner sep=3mm]
};
\node[draw, cloud, fit=(B)(C)] {uvw};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found the problem after seeing @Schrödinger's cat's answer. The problem was actually setting the `layered layout` option on the whole environment instead of just the graph. This somehow overwrites the normal positioning und puts the cloud to the right. Moving it solves the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs, graphdrawing, fit, shapes.callouts}
\usegdlibrary{layered}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  grow'=right,
  level sep=.5cm,
  sibling sep=.75cm,
  nodes={draw, circle},
]
\graph[layered layout] {
  S[rectangle, inner sep=3mm]
  -- A
  -- B[nudge down=4mm]
  -- C[nudge up=4mm]
  -- D
  -- { E -- F, G -- H }
  -- I
  -- J
  -- K
  -- Z[rectangle, inner sep=3mm]
};
\node[draw, cloud, fit=(B)(C)] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the `name` key does not name the node here in the way suggested by the code. Try `... B[name=B1, nudge down=4mm] ...` first without and then with `\node[draw, cloud, fit=(B1)(C)] {};`. However, `\node[draw, cloud, fit=(B)(C)] {};` works because the node will get the name `B`.

Comment: Yes the subgraph is also not needed. I just forgot to remove that from the MWE and now corrected this to not confuse others.

Answer (score 4):

According to the manual on p. 282, the `name` key gives the name to a (sub)graph, not to a node. However, the methods described there work fine.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs, graphdrawing, fit, shapes.callouts}
\usegdlibrary{layered}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[
layered layout,
grow'=right,
level sep=.5cm,
sibling sep=.75cm,
nodes={draw, circle},
]
\graph[]  {
  S[rectangle, inner sep=3mm]
  -- A
  -- {[name separator=-,name=grph] B[nudge down=4mm] -- C[nudge up=4mm] }
  -- D
  -- { E -- F, G -- H }
  -- I
  -- J
  -- K
  -- Z[rectangle, inner sep=3mm]
};
\end{scope}
\node[draw, cloud,fit=(grph-B)(grph-C)] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As long as your nodes have unique names, i.e. you do not use `B`, say, twice, you can just drop the `name` key altogether.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs, graphdrawing, fit, shapes.callouts}
\usegdlibrary{layered}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[
layered layout,
grow'=right,
level sep=.5cm,
sibling sep=.75cm,
nodes={draw, circle},
]
\graph[]  {
  S[rectangle, inner sep=3mm]
  -- A
  -- { B[nudge down=4mm] -- C[nudge up=4mm] }
  -- D
  -- { E -- F, G -- H }
  -- I
  -- J
  -- K
  -- Z[rectangle, inner sep=3mm]
};
\end{scope}
\node[draw, cloud,fit=(B)(C)] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your answer changes more than necessary though it helped me spot my mistake. Also thanks for referencing out the manual - it helped me with a problem I encountered after fixing this.